# Field names from dtype listing?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I'm using code from [scipy.io.loadmat nested structures (i.e. dictionaries)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008608/scipy-io-loadmat-nested-structures-i-e-dictionaries) to read a matlab structure into Python.  I want to make a list of names of fields that appear in the dtype listing.  My code is:

```
matfile   =loadmat(dataDirStr + matFileName, struct_as_record=True) # a dictionary
theseKeys = matfile.keys()            #as list
thisDict  = matfile[ theseKeys[ 1 ] ] #type = void1152, size = (1, 118)
#
#screen display of contents is:
#
dtype    = [ ( 'Aircraft_Name', 'O'), ('Low_Mass', 'O') ]
```

So, with that in mind, I would like to create a listing of the entries in dtype:

```
thisList = [ 'Aircraft_Name', 'Low_Mass' ] #etc., etc.
```

such that the order of names in the dtype entry is preserved.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension and pick up the first item from each tuple, in each iteration:

```
thisList = [item[0] for item in dtype]
```

Or as a functional approach use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
thisList = next(zip(*dtype)) # in python 2.x zip(*dtype)[0]
```

Comment: Fair enough suggestions, but how do I access 'dtype' from its location inside the dict variable?  I can send the screen-shot if that helps.

Comment: ([u'B788__'], [[99817]], [[140000]], [[160000]], [[43000]],  
    dtype=[('Aircraft_Name', 'O'), ('Low_Mass', 'O'), (

Answer (score 1):

```
In [168]: dt=np.dtype([ ( 'Aircraft_Name', 'O'), ('Low_Mass', 'O') ])
In [169]: dt
Out[169]: dtype([('Aircraft_Name', 'O'), ('Low_Mass', 'O')])
In [170]: dt.names
Out[170]: ('Aircraft_Name', 'Low_Mass')
```

This tuple is handy for setting, or fetching, all fields, one by one:

```
In [171]: x=np.empty((3,),dtype=dt)
In [172]: x
Out[172]: 
array([(None, None), (None, None), (None, None)], 
      dtype=[('Aircraft_Name', 'O'), ('Low_Mass', 'O')])
In [173]: for name in x.dtype.names:
     ...:     x[name][:]=['one','two','three']
     ...:     
In [174]: x
Out[174]: 
array([('one', 'one'), ('two', 'two'), ('three', 'three')], 
      dtype=[('Aircraft_Name', 'O'), ('Low_Mass', 'O')])
```

`descr` is a list description of the variable's dtype; names can be pulled from that as well:

```
In [180]: x.dtype.descr
Out[180]: [('Aircraft_Name', '|O'), ('Low_Mass', '|O')]
In [181]: [i[0] for i in x.dtype.descr]
Out[181]: ['Aircraft_Name', 'Low_Mass']
In [182]: x.dtype.names
Out[182]: ('Aircraft_Name', 'Low_Mass')
```

Comment: Thank you.  However, the dt variable is embedded in the dict variable, as noted above, and it's what I want to retrieve.  You've given me the information to create it, and that's fine.  But, how about dynamically creating the list from the dtype within the dict variable?  Thank you.

Comment: If `thisDict` is the variable, an array, then `thisDict.dtype` is its `dtype`, and `thisDict.dtype.names` are the field names.

Comment: Bingo.  Thanks so much.