# Change dtype data_type fields of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, octave, oct2py

I have a `.mat` file which I load using `scipy`:

```
from oct2py import octave
import scipy.io as spio
matPath = "path/to/file.mat"
matFile = spio.loadmat(matPath)
```

I get a numpy array which I want to pass to octave function using `oct2py`, like that:

```
aMatStruct = matFile["aMatStruct"]
result = octave.aMatFunction(aMatStruct)
```

But I get the following error:

```
oct2py.utils.Oct2PyError: Datatype not supported
```

It seems it's due to the array `dtype`, which looks like: `[('x', 'O'), ('y', 'O'), ('z', 'O')]`

So I thought about changing it to `'S'`, `'U'`, or something that's supported.

1. How can it be done?
2. I couldn't find a supported dtype in the [otc2py documentation](https://blink1073.github.io/oct2py/source/examples.html). Any help on that?
3. Is there a way to load the `.mat` file with another (supported) dtype? I looked [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html#scipy.io.loadmat) but couldn't find anything useful.

Note that inside `aMatFunction` it uses `aMatStruct` like that: `x = aMatStruct.x`.

Comment: can you upload a copy of your matfile and specify the exact octave function that fails?

Comment: The 'O' means 'object'.  The array has 3 fields.  What did the srray look like on the matlab source, cells, structure?  What does the oct function expect?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround!

I used the [following script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008608/scipy-io-loadmat-nested-structures-i-e-dictionaries), which reconstructs python dictionaries from the loaded struct, which `oct2py2` in turn interpret as matlab structs.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest converting the resulting array to a valid dictionary but you beat me to it so I won't code it :p

However, the other, simpler solution I was going to suggest is that, since you're only using the struct within octave, you *could* just load it into its workspace and evaluate directly. i.e. the following works for me:

```
>>> octave.load("MyFile.mat")
>>> octave.eval("fieldnames(S)")
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = name
  [2,1] = age
}
[u'name', u'age']
```

**EDIT** eh screw it, here's the python solution; I'd started it anyway :p

```
>>> from oct2py import octave
>>> from scipy.io import loadmat
>>> F = loadmat("/home/tasos/Desktop/MyFile.mat")
>>> M = F["S"] # the name of the struct variable I saved in the mat file
>>> M = M[0][0]
>>> D = {M.dtype.names[i]:M[i][0] for i in range(len(M))}
>>> out = octave.fieldnames(D); out
[u'age', u'name']
```

Comment: Not a generic solution (I have to know the struct fields), but really simple one!

Comment: Well, of course, hahah! You didn't give any detail whatsoever; you just said "a function" on "a struct", so I just improvised with an example :p Adapt as necessary :)  (having said that, that's exactly what the `fieldnames` function does, it gives you the names of a struct's fields! \o/ )