# index scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct with list

Tags: python, matlab

I have many `.mat` files that I need to bring into python and do things with. I found a method to easily deal with the `.mat` files [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008608/scipy-io-loadmat-nested-structures-i-e-dictionaries).
This works very well but now I would like to iterate over all the values. How do I do this?

```
wObs = 'path/to/matfile.mat'
mat = loadmat(wObs)
mat = mat['wObjs']

#function I wrote to get the field names of the .mat file. Returns a list of field names.
fields = mat_feildnames(wObs, 'wObjs') 

#now I want to itterate over the data and do things... 
for row in range(len(mat)):
    for field in fields:

        #field is string value.. how do I make this work?
        #this format if field is a valid field name will return what I want. 
        print(mat[row].field)


>>mat['wObjs'] 
   Returns:
   array([<scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe5e80>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe5eb8>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe7080>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe7048>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe70f0>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe71d0>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe72b0>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe7518>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe75c0>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe7668>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe76a0>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe7748>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe77f0>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe78d0>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe7940>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe79b0>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe7a20>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe7a90>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe7b00>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe7b70>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe7be0>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe7c50>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe7cc0>,
   <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f0de3fe7d30>], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-read the linked to post and figured I'd try one of the lesser responses to see what it did.. it worked.. yay! Below is the answer to my above question.

```
import scipy.io as spio

vig=spio.loadmat(wObs,squeeze_me=True)
for field in fields:
    print(vig['wObjs'][field])
```